# How can I do this SQL update query in fewer lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I am performing the following update statement. There are only 6 lines listed here but this same logic is applied across hundreds of records. It does work, but rather than repeating the Update syntax as I've done is there a way to type update and set once and somehow iterate it across all lines? As you can see the logic is not always identical. In this case I want to add _GRP but the original field value is not consistent, sometimes I want to drop some of the extra text that reads _2. This is SQL Server 2012

```
UPDATE AOOBJECT SET NAME = 'abc_GRP' WHERE NAME = 'abc_2' AND ObjectDescription = 'Portfolio Group Description'
UPDATE AOOBJECT SET NAME = 'def_GRP' WHERE NAME = 'def' AND ObjectDescription = 'Portfolio Group Description'
UPDATE AOOBJECT SET NAME = 'ghi_GRP' WHERE NAME = 'ghi' AND ObjectDescription = 'Portfolio Group Description'
UPDATE AOOBJECT SET NAME = 'jkl_GRP' WHERE NAME = 'jkl_2' AND ObjectDescription = 'Portfolio Group Description'
UPDATE AOOBJECT SET NAME = 'mno_GRP' WHERE NAME = 'mno' AND ObjectDescription = 'Portfolio Group Description'
UPDATE AOOBJECT SET NAME = 'prq_GRP' WHERE NAME = 'prq' AND ObjectDescription = 'Portfolio Group Description'
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a script in SQL Server Management Studio?  This would let you run the above 6 `UPDATE` commands all at once.

Comment: Just get rid of the line breaks. SQL Server doesn't care. Bam! One line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `CASE` and string functions `RIGHT`, `LEFT` and `LEN`

```
UPDATE AOOBJECT 
SET NAME = CASE 
               WHEN RIGHT(NAME , 2) = '_2' THEN LEFT(NAME , LEN(NAME) - 2)
               ELSE NAME 
           END + '_GRP'
WHERE ObjectDescription = 'Portfolio Group Description'
```

Comment: @lc. Thanks didn't saw that `_GRP`

Comment: No problem. Was only secondary to the logic in your query anyway, so I figured I would just add it.

Comment: I think you mean `CASE WHEN` not `CASE WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it in a single statement:

```
update adoobject
set name=case when name='abc_2' then 'abc_GRP' when name='def' then 'def_GRP' when name='ghi' then 'ghi_GRP' end
where name in ('abc_2', 'def', 'ghi') -- etc
    and objectdescription='Portfolio Group Description'
```

It will most likely be a lot faster too, since the server doesn't have to recalculate plan after plan after plan every time -- though I doubt you'll notice if you only have 6 items to change.

Comment: *I doubt you'll notice if you only have 6 items to change.* I think `CASE WHEN` with hundreds of `WHEN` statements is poor for maintainability. *There are only 6 lines listed here but this same logic is applied across hundreds of records*

Comment: You can think so, sure. However I think that applying a filter using indexes, then only touching a few records rather than every single one is better. I'm sure you know best though.